# VBA Change code from MSG Box to Summary Report

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon,

I have tried searching different forums to no avail.

I have the below VBA code that will loop through all files in a folder and generate in a msge box the total number of rows of every file looped in that folder.

What I need your help on if possible is generate a summary report.

Ideally

The summary report will show File name and show how many rows with data in column H.

```
    Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Dim folderPath As String

folderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

Filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")

Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If Application.CountA(sh.Range("H:H")) > 0 Then
            myCount = myCount + sh.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        End If
    Next
    wb.Close False
    Filename = Dir
    Set wb = Nothing
Loop

MsgBox myCount

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, so have you tried to modify that code in any way? What issues did you face?

Answer (score 0):

You could try opening a "home" workbook where all values are stored. Basically, what you'll need to do is open a new workbook, and during your loop through each of the files, you'll paste the file path and the row count in the new workbook. Hopefully this will help, or at least give you an idea of how to do what you're trying to do. `

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

Dim folderPath As String
Dim summarySheet as Workbook
set summarySheet = workbook.add

folderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

Filename = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")

Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If Application.CountA(sh.Range("H:H")) > 0 Then
            myCount = myCount + sh.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        End If
    Next
    wb.Close False
    summarySheet.activate
    Range("A:A").insert Shift:=xlDown
    Cells(1,1) = Filename
    Cells(1,2) = myCount
    Filename = Dir
    Set wb = Nothing
Loop

MsgBox myCount

End Sub`
```